# Need help designing a comparator with constraints

Tags: c, comparator

I trying to write a comparator to compare two "Signature"s. So I was thinking I can write a function that given a "Signature" it returns an integer value.

```
int *signature_to_integer(Signature *sig) {
   // TODO
}
```

However, I have two constraints:

- Comparator should include all field of the "Signature" struct
- To compare two `ASTNode`s, I need to compare them using their *line number* in the source code where they are defined

So I was thinking I can do something like this:

```
int val = is_input * 1 + is_var * 10 + line_number(source_class) * 100 + num_actuals * 1000 + ...;
```

But this is a bad idea because the line number can be greater than 1000 and it will mess up my logic. I appreciate any hint or ideas.

Thank you.

"Signature" structure:

```
struct Signature_type
{
  bool is_input;
  bool is_var;
  ASTNode source_class;
  int num_actuals;
  ASTNode actuals[];
};

typedef struct Signature_type Signature;
```

Comment: What is your comparison function to be used for? Is it supposed to be passed to e.g. `qsort`? What is it supposed to return? Just boolean "equal or not"? Or perhaps "less/greater than"? Which member fields in the structure needs to be compared? What is the priority between the member fields, is some member more important than some other?

Comment: This comparator function is used to create an ordered set. My set has to be ordered so I can quickly test whether two sets are equal without comparing each element one-by-one. The whole thing is used for a feature in a compiler. My comparator has to include all the fields of Signature and be efficient.

Comment: There is no priority between each field. All the members are equally important.

Comment: So really a "less than" comparison. Then think about how one `Signature` could be considered "less than" another `Signature`. Does it even make sense for `Signature` objects to be ordered? Perhaps all you really need is a check for *uniqueness*?

Comment: I didn't want to get into details but everything (ASTNode and Signature) is "hashcons"ed. Which means if two thing are equal we have only one instance of them. Hence to check if they are equal we can just use a reference compare ==

Comment: I need a deterministic way to compare two signatures which should use `line_number` function for ASTNode fields

Comment: Going with the uniqueness idea rather than ordering, just compare if all fields are equal. If two objects are equal, then they are the same. This can be implemented as a simple member-wise comparison using `==`.

Comment: On another note, will your language allow multiple "modules" or input source files? Do you need to compare signatures from different "modules" or source files? Then you can't really use line-numbers as a way to check for uniqueness (or ordering for that matter), neither the number and type of arguments for functions (or whatever `actuals` is supposed to represent). You could have two different function (if that's what `Signature` represents) that are exactly equal in all possible way when you look only at signature, including line numbers.

Comment: Also, if you want to compare only function signatures to see if they match, for function overloading purposes or similar, then you should not compare line numbers at all, only argument count and types, and possibly return type.

Comment: Since this is C and not C++, I don't understand how `ASTNode` or "source class" can be defined in multiple files? Isn't there a single, one and only `struct Signature_type`? Also, you are basically trying to do create a hash code, and the problem you are having is called [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and is the expected behavior of hash codes. This is most certainly the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking I can write a function that given a "Signature" it returns an integer value.
>
> I appreciate any hint or ideas.

Do not write a function that converts the object to an integer value. Instead:

> I trying to write a comparator to compare two "Signature"s

Do that. Mimic the return value of the function pointer passed to `qsort`.

```
// return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero 
// if the first argument is considered to
// be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
int signature_compare(const Signature *sig1, const Signature *sig2) {
    if (sig1->is_input != sig2->is_input) {
          // decide ordering. Should sig1 be _before_ sig2_?
          // return sig1->is_input < sig2->is_input ? -1 : 1;
          return sig1->is_input < sig2->is_input ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if (sig1->is_var != sig2->is_var) {
          return sig1->is_var - sig2->is_var;
    }
    if (line_number(sig1->source_class) != line_number(sig2->source_class)) {
           // note: substraction with int's may overflow
           // handle specific cases
           return line_number(sig1->source_class) - line_number(sig2->source_class);
    }
    // etc. etc. etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much